# How to encrypt and decrypt a const char* in WinRT

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I have been trying to write encrypt and decrypt functions whose signatures require the input and the output strings to be `void*` type only. The code works fine if the inputs can be specified as `IBuffer^` but in the other case the source string and the encrypted->decrypted string do not match.

```
CodeIBuffer^ byteArrayToIBufferPtr(byte *source, int size)
{
    Platform::ArrayReference<uint8> blobArray(source, size);
    IBuffer ^buffer = CryptographicBuffer::CreateFromByteArray(blobArray);
    return buffer;
}

byte* IBufferPtrToByteArray(IBuffer ^buffer)
{
    Array<unsigned char,1U> ^platArray = ref new Array<unsigned char,1U>(256);
    CryptographicBuffer::CopyToByteArray(buffer,&platArray);

    byte *dest = platArray->Data;
    return dest;
}

int DataEncryption::encryptData(EncryptionAlgorithm algo, int keySize, void* srcData, const unsigned int srcSize,
        void*& encData, unsigned int& encSize)
{

    LOG_D(TAG, "encryptData()");

    if(srcData == nullptr)
    {
        LOG_E(TAG,"");
        return DataEncryption::RESULT_EMPTY_DATA_ERROR;
    }
    if(srcSize == 0)
    {
        LOG_E(TAG,"");
        return DataEncryption::RESULT_SIZE_ZERO_ERROR;
    }

    IBuffer^ encrypted;
    IBuffer^ buffer;
    IBuffer^ iv = nullptr;
    String^ algName;
    bool cbc = false;

    switch (algo)
    {
    case DataEncryption::ENC_DEFAULT:
        algName = "AES_CBC";
        cbc = true;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    // Open the algorithm provider for the algorithm specified on input.
    SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider^ Algorithm = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider::OpenAlgorithm(algName);

    // Generate a symmetric key.
    IBuffer^ keymaterial = CryptographicBuffer::GenerateRandom((keySize + 7) / 8);
    CryptographicKey^ key;

    try
    {
        key = Algorithm->CreateSymmetricKey(keymaterial);
    }
    catch(InvalidArgumentException^ e)
    {
        LOG_E(TAG,"encryptData(): Could not create key.");
        return DataEncryption::RESULT_ERROR;
    }

    // CBC mode needs Initialization vector, here just random data.
    // IV property will be set on "Encrypted".
    if (cbc)
        iv = CryptographicBuffer::GenerateRandom(Algorithm->BlockLength);

    // Set the data to encrypt. 
    IBuffer ^srcDataBuffer = byteArrayToIBufferPtr(static_cast<byte*>(srcData),256);

    // Encrypt and create an authenticated tag.
    encrypted = CryptographicEngine::Encrypt(key, srcDataBuffer, iv);

    //encData = encrypted;
    byte *bb = IBufferPtrToByteArray(encrypted);
    encData = IBufferPtrToByteArray(encrypted);
    encSize = encrypted->Length;

    return DataEncryption::RESULT_SUCCESS;
}


int DataEncryption::decryptData(EncryptionAlgorithm algo, int keySize, void* encData, const unsigned int encSize,
        void*& decData, unsigned int& decSize)
{
    LOG_D(TAG, "decryptData()");

    if(encData == nullptr)
    {
        LOG_E(TAG,"");
        return DataEncryption::RESULT_EMPTY_DATA_ERROR;
    }
    if(encSize == 0)
    {
        LOG_E(TAG,"");
        return DataEncryption::RESULT_SIZE_ZERO_ERROR;
    }

    IBuffer^ encrypted;
    IBuffer^ decrypted;
    IBuffer^ iv = nullptr;
    String^ algName;
    bool cbc = false;

    switch (algo)
    {
    case DataEncryption::ENC_DEFAULT:
        algName = "AES_CBC";
        cbc = true;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    // Open the algorithm provider for the algorithm specified on input.
    SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider^ Algorithm = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider::OpenAlgorithm(algName);

    // Generate a symmetric key.
    IBuffer^ keymaterial = CryptographicBuffer::GenerateRandom((keySize + 7) / 8);
    CryptographicKey^ key;

    try
    {
        key = Algorithm->CreateSymmetricKey(keymaterial);
    }
    catch(InvalidArgumentException^ e)
    {
        LOG_E(TAG,"encryptData(): Could not create key.");
        return DataEncryption::RESULT_ERROR;
    }

    // CBC mode needs Initialization vector, here just random data.
    // IV property will be set on "Encrypted".
    if (cbc)
        iv = CryptographicBuffer::GenerateRandom(Algorithm->BlockLength);

    // Set the data to decrypt. 
    byte *cc = static_cast<byte*>(encData);
    IBuffer ^encDataBuffer = byteArrayToIBufferPtr(cc,256);
    // Decrypt and verify the authenticated tag.
    decrypted = CryptographicEngine::Decrypt(key, encDataBuffer, iv);

    byte *bb = IBufferPtrToByteArray(decrypted);
    decData = IBufferPtrToByteArray(decrypted);

    decSize = decrypted->Length;

    return DataEncryption::RESULT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Encryption. Pretty complicated field. What encryption method do you use? Are you creating your own encryption algorithm? Is your problem that you're currently encountering related with encryption? Is it just a C++ syntax/semantic misuse problem that could be solved without mentioning the word "encryption"?

Comment: Hi Mark! I am writing a wrapper to encrypt and decrypt algorithms already available in Cryptographic libraries. Previously I was using openssl third party library; now I need to use the WinRT native APIs. The logic is:

encryptData() function:
--------------------------
1. covert source string in 'const char*' format to 'IBuffer^' format 
2. Encrypt the buffer using WinRT API
3. Convert the encoded buffer back to 'char*' and install it in the destination string (argument)

Comment: decryptData() function:
--------------------------
1. covert source string in 'const char*' format to 'IBuffer^' format 
2. Decrypt the buffer using WinRT API
3. Convert the decoded buffer back to 'char*' and install it in the destination string (argument)

The problem I am facing is that if I take the arguments as IBuffer, the code works fine; but when the source and destination arguments are 'void*'; the conversion thing is doing something weird. The source string and the string resulting after encrypting and then decrypting should have matched; unfortunately that is not happening.

Comment: I assume since this is WinRT method you are using, that you are using C++/CX, not C++/CLI.  Changed tags.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the problem is with this function:

```
byte* IBufferPtrToByteArray(IBuffer ^buffer)
{
    Array<unsigned char,1U> ^platArray = ref new Array<unsigned char,1U>(256);
    CryptographicBuffer::CopyToByteArray(buffer,&platArray);

    byte *dest = platArray->Data;
    return dest;
}
```

What you're doing there is allocating a new `Platform::Array<byte>^` with 1 reference, then getting a pointer to its internally-managed storage, then returning that pointer-- at which point the Array is being dereferenced and is thus deallocating its underlying storage. Thus the pointer you return refers to freed memory. The next allocation is likely to overwrite those bytes.

What you'll need to do is take the return-by-reference `Array<byte>^` from `CopyToByteArray()` (which creates a new Array, presumably wrapping the bytes of the input `IBuffer^`, and returns it) and *copy that array's contents*.

Your end result will function similarly to this snippet from the Readium SDK project, which takes a `std::string` instance, hashes it using SHA-1, and copies the hash data into a member variable `uint8_t _key[KeySize]`:

```
using namespace ::Platform;
using namespace ::Windows::Foundation::Cryptography;
using namespace ::Windows::Foundation::Cryptography::Core;

auto byteArray = ArrayReference<byte>(reinterpret_cast<byte*>(const_cast<char*>(str.data())), str.length());
auto inBuf = CryptographicBuffer::CreateFromByteArray(byteArray);
auto keyBuf = HashAlgorithmProvider::OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames::Sha1)->HashData(inBuf);

Array<byte>^ outArray = nullptr;
CryptographicBuffer::CopyToByteArray(keyBuf, &outArray);
memcpy_s(_key, KeySize, outArray->Data, outArray->Length);
```

The steps:

1. Create an `ArrayReference<byte>` corresponding to the bytes in the `std::string` (no copying).
2. Pass that to `CryptographicBuffer::CreateFromByteArray()` to get your `IBuffer^`. Still no copying of data.
3. Call your hash/encryption function, passing the `IBuffer^` you just made. You get another `IBuffer^` in return, which may or may not be using the exact same storage (that's really up to the implementation of the algorithm, I think).
4. Create a variable of type `Array<byte>^`. Don't allocate an object, you're going to be given one by reference.
5. Pass the address of that object into `CryptographicBuffer::CopyToByteArray()` to receive a copy of your key data.
6. While that `Array^` remains valid, copy its bytes into your native array.